# Semantic Versioning for Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, semantic-versioning

My team has a fairly large set of desktop applications with many shared libraries between them all in one common solution file in our repository. We'd like to use semantic versioning for a number of reasons, chief of which is to make it easier for our users to install updates. However, given the number of assemblies we're dealing with, we're finding it pretty tedious updating AssemblyInfo files for each one, especially if it's for a library that's a dependency for multiple applications.

I was wondering if there's an easy way to use git tags or some kind of external tool to tell the build server that, for example, XYZ has a bug fix and its patch number needs to be updated.

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this is to your setup, but I use a pre-commit hook to change the version number (and a post-commit hook to trigger a build).

Comment: Thanks @nondestructive. That's kind of what I was getting at. I think the problem in our case is we'd have to also specify which assembly was getting changed, since they're in a common solution/repo.

Comment: I see, I think I over-simplified your situation.

Comment: Or I over-complicated it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use GitVersion : https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It will do automatically the semantic versionning based on the last tag and git history.

You could use GitVersionTask if you use msbuild or (better) use it with build tools like fake or cake.net

Edit: you now have also alternatives easier to use : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/, https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitInfo/,. ..